# Visual Studio will not stop breaking on exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, exception, xunit

I'm writing a xUnit.net DNX test library following the instructions [here](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html). I have a lot of `Assert.Throws` clauses in my tests, which is a problem because for some reason Visual Studio will not stop breaking on exceptions thrown by the clauses. It says the exceptions are ["unhandled by user code,"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4MP.png) and then happily goes on to show me more of these exceptions after that one is caught.

I have tried checking and unchecking all the checkboxes in `Debug > Exception Settings...`, but to no avail. The debugger breaks on the exceptions every single time. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you are debugging the code then the exception is obvious. It always be thrown in normal situations as well. But It should not cross the boundary of  your test which expect to throw an exception and test should pass as expected. What else problem you're facing apart from afore mentioned scenario?

Comment: @vendettamit All the tests are passing, but the debugger simply won't stop breaking.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just *running* the unit tests, or *debugging* the unit tests?

Are you sure that you've unchecked the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in the Debug -> Exceptions menu?

[image]

If you've unchecked that and are still getting it breaking, then I'm not sure how to help you. Have you taken a look at [Managing Exceptions with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)?

Comment: I'm debugging, yeah. When I run the project it works fine, but I need to hit a breakpoint on one of the tests. Can you do that while running?

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2017 there is no User-unhandled column in the Exception Settings window.

So if you are debugging and want VS to stop breaking on user-unhandled exceptions -- for example, because they are logged and passed on to ASP.NET -- this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger) details how to do it.

Specifically:

> 1. In the Exception Settings window, open the context menu by right-clicking in window and then selecting Show Columns. (If you have turned off Just My Code, you will not see this command.)
> 2. You should see a second column named Additional Actions. This column displays Continue when unhandled by user code on specific exceptions, meaning that the debugger does not break if that exception is not handled in user code but is handled in external code.
> 3. You can change this setting either for a particular exception (select the exception, right-click, and select/deselect Continue when Unhandled in User Code) or for an entire category of exceptions (for example, all the Common Language Runtime exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I used all the newest features of the "new Exception Helper" to try to disable break on First chance exception but the UI checkbox changes had no effect on the underlying debugger.

The following worked for me:

**Tools - Options => Debugging => General => Uncheck "Use the new Exception Helper"**

After that the classic dialog popped up during debugging. Unchecking exceptions in the classic dialog box worked.

[Options/Debugger/NewExceptionHandler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DAhb.png)